# Lack of an article in "looking for work"

Tags: grammar, articles

Should there be an Indefinite article in a quote "Looking for work" or that is a correct way to say it?

As I see it, it's just "the way we say it in English" is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sense of 'work' is not countable.

[Work](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/work) (MW, noun definition 1a)

> activity that a person engages in regularly to earn a livelihood - *people looking for work*

Contrast that with 'job', which is countable.

> Now that I've graduated from college, I need to get a job.
>
> She has 2 jobs; she's a full-time secretary, and she tends bar on Friday and Saturday nights.